# Error when using NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindowcontroller

I just started a new Cocoa project after a long time... And I don't know why, but I always get an error when calling a xib by a NSWindowController. What I do is really very simple: I have a new project as a starting point and then I don't wantz to call the xib from Appdelegate, but from a subclass of NSWindowController. Then the output tells me that:

> 2014-11-12 09:58:18.519 SimpleTest[8554:378690] ApplePersistence=NO
>
> 2014-11-12 09:58:18.671 SimpleTest[8554:378690] Failed to connect (window) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSWindow): missing setter or instance variable

Okay, how does it look in code? My Appdelegate looks like this:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainWindowController.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
@property (strong) MainWindowController *mainWindowController;

@end

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    _mainWindowController = [[MainWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"MainMenu"];
    [self.mainWindowController showWindow:self];
}

@end
```

Nothing special so far. The `MainWindowController` looks like this:

```
#import "MainWindowController.h"

@interface MainWindowController ()
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@end

@implementation MainWindowController

- (id)initWithWindow:(NSWindow *)window
{
    self = [super initWithWindow:window];

    if (self != nil)
    {
        //do something
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

And again very simple... Additiponally I have some modifications in IB: File'Owner of MainMenu.xib becomes `MainWindowController`. Its 'window' outlet is connected to the Window of the application. The delegate of Window is connected to File's Owner. Well, that's it! But why do I receive this error? What am I doing wrong?

---EDIT---
this shows the connections in IB

[image: conncections]

Comment: "Its 'window' outlet is connected to the Window of the application" would seem wrong; given `MainWindowController` is not the application or appdelegate.

Comment: it's neiither the application nor the appdelegate. What exactly is wrong then?

Comment: You said it was connected to the window of the application.

Comment: What window else? There is only one window!

Comment: OK, I understand.  It looks like the original `MainMenu.xib` file is still in the app bundle and trying to connect to the Application's `window` outlet?

Comment: Yes, exactly! That's it!

Comment: So... What was the answer? I'm getting a similar error message for my app after upgrading to Yosemite.

Comment: did you got answer?

Comment: use initWithWindowNibName: not initWithWindowNibName:owner: and dont forget to wire window to file owner. File owner should be NSWindowController or any custom subclass

Answer (score 2):

The most important is using right selector to create new instance and having all wired up correctly.

Steps:
1. Add new xib with window or an empty one and add window to it

[image]

2.Select File owner and set it to NSWindowController or its subclass.

[image]

3. Select window and connect it to File owner

[image]

4. Make new NSWindowController instance

> 

```
  - (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
  {
      NSWindowController *windowController = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Window"];
      [NSApp runModalForWindow:[windowController window]];
  }
```

[image]